# Speeding up hair editing

Tags: particles, edit-mode, performance, hair

The first time I saw the hair system in blender, I was able to style it in the particle editing view without much of a problem. That was on a cheap laptop. Now I'm working on a system with two bridged hybrid GeForce GTX 980 TI's, 32 GB of RAM, and a Core i7-5930K 6 core CPU clocked at 3.5 GHz. It can handle any game I throw at it without a hitch. But ask it to edit a couple hundred hair particles? Maybe a hair here and there will change before Blender crashes. It doesn't matter if I put it in CUDA mode or not. I'm at my wits end here.

**Edit:**

If I disconnect the hair from the emitter, I can manipulate it freely. Except, I really can't have the hair disconnected from the person's head.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what was happening. I made the body itself the emitter, which is very high poly, and had a large deflect emitter distance. There were actually about a thousand hairs, each of which was being calculated against every single vertex in the body.

Comment: How about setting the count of the hair to 0 and add the hair you need manually with the particle editor? I barely use the hair emitter, but that's how it's easiest for me. Also, I only place the hair tip and hair root and subdivide every hair curve that I want to define better. That way, your computer won't be exhausted too soon, since I guess you only need the hair for the head, right?^^ Hope this helps you (=